# Rails impossible to render partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, renderpartial

I'm using the gems "haml" and "haml-rails" in my rails app and I have this folder structure

```
-views
  -layouts
    -public
      -layout.html.haml
      -_header.html.haml
      -_footer.html.haml
```

And i wanto to render _header and _footer in layout.html.haml using this code:

```
= render 'layouts/public/_header'
 .container= yield
= render 'layouts/public/_footer'
```

but rails raises a MissingTemplate error but _header and _footer exists...

how can i solve?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You typically omit the underscores when specifying partial names in these helpers. Also, you should be passing them in as a `:partial` parameter:.

```
= render :partial => 'layouts/public/header'
 .container= yield
= render :partial => 'layouts/public/footer'
```

Answer (score 2):

> partials are named with a leading underscore to distinguish them from
>   regular views, even though they are referred to without the
>   underscore.

source: [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-partials)